# I am trying to change write a line of C# code to change the end of a line in powerpoint to be rounded

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am creating powerpoint slides from c#. I am able to add a line and set some of its features:

```
myLine = roundTableSlide.Shapes.AddLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
myLine.Line.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
myLine.Line.Weight = minWidth + (connections[i, j] / weightingFactor) ;
myLine.Line.Style = MsoLineStyle.msoLineSingle;
```

But I can't seem to set the ends of the line to 'rounded'. I know the value I want to set is 'MsoLineCapStyle.msoLineCapRound', but I can't seem to find what to apply it to. ChatGPT and Bard are telling me that the Line object should have a LineCap attribute, but it doesn't seem to. Any help much appreciated.

Tried MyLine.Line.LineCap = MsoLineCapStyle.msoLineCapRound
Also Tried MyLine.LineCap = MsoLineCapStyle.msoLineCapRound
Also tried to use a LineFormat object.
None of them had a lineCap attribute, so couldn't get them to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that ChatGPT is hallucinating wrt this one! The MsoLineCapStyle
enumeration does exist in the [Office library](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/msolinecapstyle-enumeration-office) but it's only implemented in the [Publisher Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/publisher.lineformat.capstyle). Not very clear in the Microsoft documentation. This mans your only options are to simulate the UX to change the cap type (nasty) or modify the XML of the PowerPoint file. Sending feedback to Microsoft via the Help tab might also be useful but they rarely add things to the OM these days.